# problem uploading app binary to app store

Tags: iphone, app-store, submission

I have used itunes connect to add the app summary one night. The release date was given as that day. But when i had to upload the binary the first page i encountered was one that asked me about whether i use encryption . I use only authentication encryption so i selected that option but couldn't proceed as the page kept loading and then the session timed out. I kept retrying but the same thing kept happening. So i tried to do it the next day but the option to upload has been removed from the app summary. This could be because the release date was given as yesterday. Now how do i upload the app binary ? :( There seems to be no option to edit the release date.
I don't want to delete the app summary and add it again as then i wont be able to use the same app name. Plz help! Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The upload date doesn't make a difference here. Try logging into https://itunesconnect.apple.com and select Manage your applications. Then fill out the details of the app and click ready to upload binary.

From Xcode 4 organiser upload your binary signed with the correct dev certificate and if all goes well your app status on itunesconnect will be changed to `"Waiting for review"`

Comment: thanks , but i am unable to find the 'ready to upload binary' button

Comment: infact there is no such button found now, it was there the other day

Comment: Well then delete the binary and create new application.

Answer (score 0):

I had already filled the details and clicked the ready to upload binary button. 
I later found **Application Loader** , a Mac Application , which guided me through the uploading build process. The Application Loader app is available on the iPhone SDK 3.2 or later development system. Hence the problem is solved.